# Bluetooth mouse won't connect, after turning Bluetooth off it won't turn back on

Tags: bootcamp, windows, bluetooth, mojave, dual-boot

Fresh install of Boot Camp on macOS Mojave with a Windows 10 ISO from the Microsoft website. I'm trying to connect my Bluetooth mouse (which works fine and connects on macOS Mojave) to Windows and it won't find the mouse.

- I have disconnected and removed the mouse from macOS.
- I have tried 'updating' my Bluetooth radio to "Apple Broadcom Built-in Bluetooth".

  - Doing this results in no Bluetooth functionality with the device showing error code 10 in Device Manager.

The current configuration for my Bluetooth settings in Device Manager is:

- Bluetooth

  - Bluetooth Radio
  - Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator
  - Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerator

Now the weird thing. Whenever I go into the general Bluetooth settings to add a device, if I use the toggle to turn Bluetooth on/off, I can turn it off, but then I can't turn it back on unless I uninstall and reinstall the driver, or restart my machine.

---

**Windows OS**

DESKTOP-4BSAGG1

- OS Name: Microsoft Windows 10 Home
- OS Version: 10.0.17134 N/A Build 17134
- OS Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation
- OS Configuration: Standalone Workstation
- OS Build Type: Multiprocessor Free

**MacBook Specs**

- 13-inch Macbook Pro (w/ Touch Bar)
- Running macOS Mojave (Latest Version)
- Bootcamp v6.1

Comment: I apologize. Someone flagged either this post or the answer as misleading. We don’t delete wrong information generally. Can that person make a clear comment what is wrong and be sure to use votes to show when a post isn’t useful.

Comment: Having the same problem with a mid-2014 15-inch MacBook Pro Retina running Catalina. Still no solution. // Also having some BlueTooth peripherals randomly stop working for a few days (persistently across restrats) only on Windows and randomly start working again for a few days or weeks afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

- create a USB drive with windows support software using Bootcamp Assistant (mac os)
- go to windows and install that support software from the USB drive
- go back to macOS
- remove ALL Bluetooth devices from mac os
- set windows as the startup drive
- restart and open windows (click mouse and keyboard when you see windows logo)
- go to Bluetooth settings and try to connect

worked for me ...for a moment...then I lost it when I set macOS as startup drive.